Как сделать кнопки, которые будут сохранять данные, введенные пользователем
Пишу программу, сохраняющюю данные пользователя. Нужно для кнопок "Сохранить" написать код, чтобы введенные пользователем данные сохранялись (желательно в базе данных sql). Только разобрался с Tkinter, тут еще с базой данных разбираться, а времени нет. Помогите скорее, пожалуйста
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3 as sql

win = tk.Tk()
win.title('Сохранятель')
win.geometry('390x310')
win.resizable(False, False)

def delete_catalog():
    selection = catalogs_listbox.curselection()
    try:
        catalogs_listbox.delete(selection[0])
    except IndexError:
        messagebox.showinfo('Внимание!', 'Выберите элемент, который хотите удалить')

def add_catalog():
    new_catalog = catalog_entry.get()
    if len(new_catalog) > 0:
        catalogs_listbox.insert(0, new_catalog)
        catalog_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    if len(new_catalog) == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo('Внимание!', 'Введите название папки!')

intro = tk.Label(text='Введите название сервиса, для которого сохраняете данные')
intro.configure(font=('Times New Roman', 11))
intro.place(x=5, y=5)

# Строка для создания папок
catalog_entry = tk.Entry(width=21)
catalog_entry.configure(font=('Times New Roman', 15))
catalog_entry.place(x=51, y=30)
add_catalog_btn = tk.Button(text="Добавить", width=9, command=add_catalog)
add_catalog_btn.place(y=30, x=268)

catalogs_listbox = tk.Listbox(width=29, height=9)
catalogs_listbox.configure(font=('Times New Roman', 15))
catalogs_listbox.place(x=49, y=60)

# По нажатию элемента Listbox выводится окно с данными
def on_select(event):
    widget = event.widget
    selection = widget.curselection()
    if selection:
        data_window = tk.Tk()
        data_window.title('Данные')
        data_window.geometry('390x65')
        data_window.resizable(False, False)

        login_label = tk.Label(master=data_window, text='Логин')
        login_label.place(x=15, y=5)
        login_entry = tk.Entry(master=data_window, width=30)
        login_entry.place(x=100, y=5)

        password_label = tk.Label(master=data_window, text='Пароль')
        password_label.place(x=15, y=35)
        password_entry = tk.Entry(master=data_window, width=30)
        password_entry.place(x=100, y=35)

        save_datas = tk.Button(master=data_window, text='Сохранить')
        save_datas.place(x=300, y=15)

        data_window.mainloop()


catalogs_listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_select)

# # Кнопка сохранения
save_program = tk.Button(master=win, text='Сохранить')
save_program.place(x=200, y=278)

# Спрятанный ползунок
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=catalogs_listbox.yview)
scrollbar.grid_forget()
catalogs_listbox["yscrollcommand"] = scrollbar.set

delete_catalog = tk.Button(text="Удалить", command=delete_catalog)
delete_catalog.configure(font=('Times New Roman', 10))
delete_catalog.place(x=286, y=278)

win.mainloop()


Если сложно с базами данных, пробуйте с файлами. Пробуйте хоть как-то. Если что-то конкретное не будет получаться - задавайте вопрос.
